# Equalities involving complex numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Could someone help me to solve these problems?

Find $x, y \in \mathbb R$ such that

1. $\displaystyle e^{x+iy}=−1$
2. $\displaystyle\frac{1+i}{1-i} =xe^{iy}$

Comment: Please show what you have tried. Do you understand what you have to do? Do you know about the polar form of a number?

Comment: do you mean $$\frac{1+i}{1-i}=xe^{iy}$$

Comment: at the same time apply these equations?

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner Hopefully they're not intended to hold for the same $x,y$ as that would be impossible :-)

Comment: Hint: for the first one, write $-1$ in the form $re^{i\theta}$, and in the second one, do the same with $(1+i)/(1-i)$.

Comment: Equate the magnitudes and arguments of both sides.  What can you conclude?

Comment: I've done the change to polar form but still don't know how's the procedure to find which is y and x.